# Virtuemart add to cart, price details etc not appearing

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I have Joomla virtuemart site and I accidently uninstalled Virtuemart but luckly I had a backup so I overwritten most of the files to the server again with some MySQL data into the databases but I can't seem to get the price and add to cart etc details showing up in the product detail page.

Is there a reason why this is happening? Have I missed a certain table or database?

I'm not sure which file I should be looking at in terms of product details page...

Thank you for your help.

Below is the code for the product details page:

```
<?php if( !defined( '_VALID_MOS' ) && !defined( '_JEXEC' ) ) die( 'Direct Access to '.basename(__FILE__).' is not allowed.' );
mm_showMyFileName(__FILE__);
require_once ( CLASSPATH. 'ps_product.php');
$ps_product = new ps_product;

 ?>
<div id="ttn_prdDetail_wrapper"><div id="product_list_inner1"><div id="product_list_inner2"><div id="product_list_inner3">
<?php if( $this->get_cfg( 'product_navigation', 1 )) {
    if( !empty( $previous_product )) {
        echo '<a class="previous_page" href="'.$previous_product_url.'">'.shopMakeHtmlSafe($previous_product['product_name']).'</a>';
    }
    if( !empty( $next_product )) {      
        echo '<a class="next_page" href="'.$next_product_url.'">'.shopMakeHtmlSafe($next_product['product_name']).'</a>';
    }
} ?>
<br clear="all"/>
    <?php $ttn_prdName = explode('|',$product_name,2);?>
    <h1 class="prdName">

        <?php echo $ttn_prdName[0] ?> <?php echo $edit_link ?>
    </h1>
    <div class="prdImages">
        <div class="mainImage">
        <?php  echo $product_image ?>
        </div>
        <h2> More images (click to enlarge)</h2>
        <div id="altviews">
            <div class="alter_img">
            <?php  echo $product_image2 ?>
            </div>
            <?php  echo $this->vmlistAdditionalImages( $product_id, $images ) ?>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prdDesc_wrapper">
        <?php echo $product_description ?>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div></div></div></div>
<!--Show bottom note ò prdoduct--->
<div class="prdBotNote">
        <?php echo $this->get_cfg('ttn_botnote')?>
    </div>
<?php
// Show Featured Products
if( $this->get_cfg( 'showFeatured', 1 )) {
    /* featuredproducts(random, no_of_products,category_based) no_of_products 0 = all else numeric amount
    edit featuredproduct.tpl.php to edit layout */
?>
    <div id="ttn-fp"><div id="ttn-fp-inner1"><div id="ttn-fp-inner2"><div id="ttn-fp-inner3">
<?php
    echo $ps_product->ttnfeaturedProducts(true,50,true);
?>
    </div></div></div></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Below is the list of the tables I have...I'm not sure I'm missing any table:

```
jos_vm_auth_group
 jos_vm_auth_user_group
 jos_vm_auth_user_vendor
 jos_vm_cart
 jos_vm_category
 jos_vm_category_xref
 jos_vm_country
 jos_vm_coupons
 jos_vm_creditcard
 jos_vm_csv
 jos_vm_currency
 jos_vm_export
 jos_vm_function
 jos_vm_manufacturer
 jos_vm_manufacturer_category
 jos_vm_module
 jos_vm_orders
 jos_vm_order_history
 jos_vm_order_item
 jos_vm_order_payment
 jos_vm_order_status
 jos_vm_order_user_info
 jos_vm_payment_method
 jos_vm_product
 jos_vm_product_attribute
 jos_vm_product_attribute_sku
 jos_vm_product_category_xref
 jos_vm_product_discount
 jos_vm_product_download
 jos_vm_product_files
 jos_vm_product_mf_xref
 jos_vm_product_price
 jos_vm_product_product_type_xref
 jos_vm_product_relations
 jos_vm_product_reviews
 jos_vm_product_type
 jos_vm_product_type_parameter
 jos_vm_product_votes
 jos_vm_shipping_carrier
 jos_vm_shipping_label
 jos_vm_shipping_rate
 jos_vm_shopper_group
 jos_vm_shopper_vendor_xref
 jos_vm_state
 jos_vm_tax_rate
 jos_vm_userfield
 jos_vm_userfield_values
 jos_vm_user_info
 jos_vm_vendor
 jos_vm_vendor_category
 jos_vm_waiting_list
 jos_vm_zone_shipping
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have a `jos_vm_weblinks` table, but I doubt that will be the cause of the problem.  You say that you have 'overwritten most of the files to the server again'; how did you do this?  If you have not done so already, perhaps a completely fresh install of Joomla/Virtuemart would help?  You could then simply delete the DB schema that it installs and replace it with your own once again.

I would also suggest checking your error logs (`/logs/error.txt`) to see if anything is getting reported.  It couldn't hurt to check your Apache error logs either.  Also, have you checked that you have inserted your old DB info correctly?  I know that's a very obvious thing to suggest, but I'm always doing silly  things like that!

Comment: My database is more than 150 mb which is sql file and I'm not sure How I can insert this in one go...Thanks for the suggestion. I seem to have trouble with getting add to shopping cart button coming out and some other text files and buttons...

Comment: Do you have a .SQL mysqldump (or equivalent) of the SQL?  If so, what does happen if you copy and paste that directly into the MySQL console?

Comment: I found out a reason why! The SQL dump was there but somehow text column with product description was not inserting all the details! I think this is due to large amount of html codes per row. Is there a way to override this and insert all regardless of amount of text data?

Comment: I found out a solution! We could use Long Text instead of just TEXT! Problem solved! Hope this helps people who are struggling as it took long time for me to solve this proble!!!!